How to read Excel file using polars?
I am trying to convert this piece of code to polars. But not able to find polars equivalent to read excel with the same arguments.
Here's the pandas approach:
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=2, dtype={'amount': str, 'date': object},
                                    na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False)


Are you not able to use https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html ?

I am able to use the pl.read_excel() but not all arguments are available just like pandas
file_path, header=2, dtype={'amount': str, 'date': object, na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False

Can you add code that creates a sample file and show the expected output Polars dataframe? header=2 in Polars would be read_options={"header_row": 2} - but it's not clear what 'date': object is intended to do for Polars.

There is also no special na_values parsing, so the default Polars behaviour should be equivalent. But some sample input/output would make it possible to give an actual answer.

Polars has several optional 3rd party libraries that read excel files which don't have all the same parameters. As such there are the catch-all engine_options and read_options. For the default library, calamine, only the latter is used. The docs to those options are here, under load_sheet.
I don't use pandas so I'm not sure if these are at parity but it'd be something like this:
df = pl.read_excel(file_path, read_options = dict(
    header_row=2, 
    dtypes={'amount': 'string', 'date': 'date'},
    ## What are these supposed to do? 
    # Convert empty Excel strings to null or other way around?
    # na_values=[''], 
    # No idea for...
    # keep_default_na=False
    )
)

Note for dtypes see this line from the doc for the strings it's looking for.
DType = typing.Literal['null', 'int', 'float', 'string', 'boolean', 'datetime', 'date', 'duration']


A possible solution, based on the idea of converting a pandas dataframe to a polars dataframe:
import polars as pl

pl_df = pl.DataFrame(df)


Thanks. this is is one way of doing it. But is there a way to directly read excel in polars with any pandas equivalent arguments
args:
file_path, header=2, dtype={'amount': str, 'date': object,
na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False

As far as I know, there is no way of using pl.read_excel directly with the parameters you need. So, maybe the best way is to use pandas and then converting the pandas dataframe to a polars one.

Thanks! solution by @dean-macgregor worked using polars read_excel! I first read the excel file with header_row and dtypes. Than applied replacing NA operation separately on the df.
Also, found a way that's much faster to read excel files using python-calamine
from python_calamine import CalamineWorkbook

workbook = CalamineWorkbook.from_path("sample.xlxs")
sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(workbook.sheet_names[0])
sheet_data = sheet.to_python(skip_empty_area=False)

headers = sheet_data[2]
rows = sheet_data[3:]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
data_df.replace({'': np.nan}, inplace=True)
data_df = data_df.astype({
    "some_column": object,
    # other columns
})

For me this reduced the time by 75%
